# Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onClick is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am novice in `react` and try to build an `api`.
My issue is the `props` i am passing from child to parent component using `onClick` function is throwing error.
I even tried to use this keyword but i can't figure out what's wrong is going on.

I figured out that my `StockContent` component is not receiving the `showOverlay` props which i am passing from body component

I am intended to navigate to the current click content by changing it url using onClick functionality..

the whole project is here ... https://github.com/Kushan-/stockStimulation

```
{
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import StockContent from '../bodyRoutes/StockContent.js'
    import ShareOverlay from '../bodyRoutes/SharesOverlay.jsx'

    const pushState = (obj, url) => window.history.pushState(obj, '', url);

    class Main extends React.Component{
        state = {
            content: []
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/data',
                context: this,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET'
            }).done(function (res) {
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({
                    content:res
                });
            })
        }

        componentWillUnmount(){
            //clean timers, listners
        }

        fetchStock = (stockName, stockId) => {
            const url = '/'+stockName+'/'+stockId;
            const obj = {currentStockName :  stockName, currentStockId : stockId}
            pushState(obj,url);

            this.setState({
                currentStockName: stockName,
                currentStockId: stockId
            })
        };

        displayPop(){
            if(this.state.currentStockId) {
                console.log(this.state.content[this.state.currentStockId]);
                const data= this.state.content[this.state.currentStockId];
                return(<div className="row" ><ShareOverlay stockData={data}/></div>)
            }
            return(<StockContent showOverlay={this.fetchContent} content={this.state.content}/>)
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    {this.displayPop()}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Main;
}
```

Comment: @Mayank - I don't think so as it was working fine before implementing this functionality. Moreover i am following https://www.lynda.com/Express-js-tutorials/Learning-Full-Stack-JavaScript-Development-MongoDB-Node-React/533304-2.html this tutorial to make the application.

Comment: Your component doesn't have a `fetchContent` method, maybe you meant to pass `fetchStock`?

Comment: right you are thank you @Nupur....